# Random beeps occur while computer is running, but idle

Tags: motherboard, alert

Sometimes, while my computer is running, it starts to beep.

The beeping only starts after several hours of user inactivity, and it ends when I press a key or move the mouse.

The beeps are not of a uniform length - there might be short beeps alongside long beeps. However I think that, on each beeping seizure, the beeps become longer and longer until they become continuous.

I think that the beeps are coming from the speaker inside the computer, as their sound is similar to the startup beep.

What can cause those beeps and how can I find what is causing them in my case?

OS: Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1

Processor (from System Properties window): Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E6550 @ 2.33GHz

(If some other data is needed then please ask and I will edit it in.)

Comment: Depending on your computer or Motherboard(if you built the computer) the manufacturer may have a "beep" code on line. something like two short beeps, ram error. One long beep CPU fan error or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

The beep might be a hardware problem, but if caused by a a program then
it should be easy to identify :

While the beeping is going on, right-click the audio icon in the
notification area and click on *Open Volume Mixer*.
Under "Applications" you can see which application(s)
is currently playing audio.

Another method would be to use
[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653)
to search for open handles by entering <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
and searching for common extensions like `.wav` and `.mp3` etc.